# Where is the rest of Oracle's V$ view definitions?

Tags: oracle

The view [`V$FIXED_VIEW_DEFINITION`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/V-FIXED_VIEW_DEFINITION.html) contains the definition of all `V$` views. However, the datatype is `VARCHAR2(4000)`, so only the first 4000 characters of the view's body are displayed:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, data_length 
  FROM dba_tab_cols 
 WHERE table_name = 'V_$FIXED_VIEW_DEFINITION';

COLUMN_NAME      DATA_TYPE  DATA_LENGTH
---------------  ---------  -----------
VIEW_NAME        VARCHAR2           128
VIEW_DEFINITION  VARCHAR2          4000
CON_ID           NUMBER              22
```

This works fine for views which are shorter, but for others, like `V$SESSION`, the query text stops right after character 4000:

```
SELECT * FROM v$fixed_view_definition WHERE view_name = 'GV$SESSION';

VIEW_NAME   VIEW_DEFINITION
----------  --------------------------------------------
GV$SESSION  select s.inst_id, ... ,decode(bitand(s.ksuse
                                 here it stops abruptly ^
```

Now, obviously, Oracle has stored the full text somewhere, and the function [`DBMS_UTILITY. EXPAND_SQL_TEXT T`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_UTILITY.html#GUID-A25FF5B4-27BF-4DC0-95B2-EE4BBD09F53C) reconstructs the full query, but not without doing strange things to the query like quoting all columns, introducing alias etc:

```
DECLARE
  c CLOB;
  i NUMBER := 1;
  linelen CONSTANT NUMBER := 100;
BEGIN
  DBMS_UTILITY.EXPAND_SQL_TEXT('SELECT * FROM V$SESSION', c);
  LOOP 
    EXIT WHEN i > DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(c);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(c, linelen, i));
    i := i + linelen;
  END LOOP;
END; 
/


SELECT "A1"."SADDR" "SADDR","A1"."SID" "SID","A1"."SERIAL#" "SERIAL#","A1"."AUDS
ID" "AUDSID","A1"."PADDR" "PADDR","A1"."USER#" "USER#","A1"."USERNAME" "USERNAME
...
```

So, where is the rest of the V$ query bodies?

Comment: I've [seen sites claim](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_x$_tables.htm) that the fixed view create scripts are in `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin` somewhere, but I don't see them.

Comment: @kfinity: Thanks for the hint. Burleson is wrong (as so often), they are *used* in rdbms/admin, but not defined there. However, your hint led me to grep the whole $ORACLE_HOME, they seem to be compiled into the Oracle binary. I found the whole definition of V$SESSION there by grepping for the start of the view body: `strings bin/oracle | grep 's.ksuseser,s.ksuudses,s.ksusepro`.  Do you want to post an answer so that I can credit your idea?

Comment: It's easier with SQL Developer which was implemented with the same package you tried with

Comment: @Suresh: Can you elaborate, I don't get what you mean...

Comment: Check this [link](https://sqlmaria.com/2018/03/13/how-to-determine-which-view-to-use/).At end of he article there is reference about SQL Developer

Comment: Wow, it's a cool feature to show the expanded sql text. It's not the orignal view body, but still slick and interesting, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it is not convenient now for me to try this myself, but V$FIXED_VIEW_DEFINITION gets the select statement from column `sys.X$KQFVT.kqftpsel`.  If you have access to `SYS` in your database, maybe see what you can do with that, whether it's possible to get more than 4000 characters out of, maybe with a `CAST()`?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I was thinking along those lines, too. kqftpsel seems to be a wrapper to a C memory structure, exposing only the first 4000 bytes to SQL. Maybe the full query is somewhere in memory, but I don't know how poke around Oracle's memory structures. `ADDR` of the view you mention has 32 bytes per V$ view, so the query body needs to be stored somewhere else, but where???

Comment: @wolφi Do you need the fixed view definitions for a specific reason, or are you just curious? When I asked [this similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/118478/3336), I was trying to fix an NLS performance problem. I ended up not needing the view definition because the problem could be fixed by updating a system table and the view was automatically rebuilt.

Comment: @JonHeller I was looking for the source of the SCN in v$database.current_scn vs dbms_flashback.get_system_change_number, hoping that they come from the same source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of having a clean answer, it sounds like you discovered the full fixed view source queries compiled into the Oracle binary by using

```
strings $ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracle
```

and grepping the output for a specific view.

[Burleson had provided a hint](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_x%24_tables.htm) that the fixed view synonyms are created by the `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/` catalog scripts (specifically `cdfixed.sql`).

Comment: It looks like as if the fixed tables and views are compiled into Oracle's binary. $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/cdfixed.sql creates "normal" V_$ views to access those special binary tables and views.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
spool C:\Users\test\Downloads\VW_DDL.txt
SET LONG 200000 LONGCHUNKSIZE 500000 PAGESIZE 0 LINESIZE 1000 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF TRIMSPOOL ON
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('VIEW', view_name, 'SYSADM')
FROM   all_views
WHERE  owner      = 'SYSADM'
AND    view_name IN (' ');
SET PAGESIZE 14 LINESIZE 100 FEEDBACK ON VERIFY ON
spool off
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The V$ view bodies are not in all_views (or dba_views), only the funny recursive stuff (SELECT ... FROM gv$session), see f.i. [here](https://rbikblog.wordpress.com/2016/06/19/viewing-fixed-view-definition/#more-355)